# Distance between solutions of two first-order ODEs

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, gradient-flows

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be a twice-continuously differentiable function, and $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth concave function. For a given initial condition $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$, consider the gradient system applied to $f$,
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot x(t) = -\nabla f(x(t))
\\x(0)=x_0
\end{cases},\qquad t\geq 0,
$$
and the gradient system applied to $\varphi\circ f$,
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot z(t) = -\nabla (\varphi \circ f)(z(t)) = -\varphi'(f(z(t))\nabla f(z(t))
\\z(0)=x_0
\end{cases},\qquad t\geq 0.
$$
My question is, can we relate the two systems, that is, does there exist an homeomorphism $H$ such that $\forall t\geq 0$, $x(t)=H(z(t))$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a parameter change $t=\alpha(s)$ the derivative of $x$ becomes
$$
\frac{d}{ds} x(α(s))=\dot x(α(s))α'(s)=-α'(s)∇f(x(α(s)))
$$
So if you set
$$
α'(s)=φ'(f(x(α(s)))),
$$
then $x(t) = x(α(s))=z(s)$ follows, at least as long as $α$ remains monotonously increasing.

Comment: That is what I was looking for, thank you!